# ODE $2yy'' - 3(y')^2 = 4 y^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the equation by using these substitutions (how it was suggested in my textbook):
$$ y = e^{z(x)} \implies y' = z'y \implies y'' = y((z')^2 + z'') $$ 
The result is:
$$ 2y^2((z')^2 + z'') - 3y^2(z')^2 = 4y^2 \implies 2z'' - (z')^2 =  4$$
Here I'm stuck and I can't figure out a way to simplify it or reduce the order of the equation. What should I do then?

Comment: It's possible there was a typo or you copied it wrong, but it looks like it should be $y'=z'y$.

Comment: Check your calculation once again, you did mistakes two times..!!

Comment: you can let $z'=p$,then $z''=p\dfrac{dp}{dy}$

Comment: @Chiranjeev Thanks for the point, I corrected the answer, but any way I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your method

$$ 2z'' - (z')^2 = 4 $$

Let $p = z'$

$$ 2p' = 4+p^2 $$

This equation is seperable
$$ \frac{1}{4+p^2}\,p' = \frac{1}{2} $$

Integrate
$$ \int\frac{2}{4+p^2}\,dp = \frac{t}{2} + C$$

Answer (score 4):

you can use other substitutions

let $y'=p$,then
$$y''=\dfrac{dp}{dx}=\dfrac{dp}{dy}\cdot\dfrac{dy}{dx}=p\dfrac{dp}{dy}$$
so
$$2yp\cdot\dfrac{dp}{dy}=3p^2+4y^2$$
then
$$\dfrac{dp}{dy}=\dfrac{3p}{2y}+\dfrac{4y}{p}$$
let $\dfrac{p}{y}=u$,then have
$$\dfrac{dp}{dy}=u+\dfrac{du}{dy}\cdot y$$
so
$$\dfrac{2u}{u^2+8}du=\dfrac{dy}{y}$$
then $u^2+8=C_{1}y$,

then it is easy to find it

Comment: A very beautiful solution! But I would like to finish my way just to follow the textbook.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=2u,z'=2u',z''=2u''$.  Then

$$4u''-4u'^2=4$$
$$\frac{u''}{u'^2+1}=1$$
$$\tan^{-1}u'=x+a$$
$$u'=\tan(x+a)$$
$$u=-\ln[\cos(x+a)]+b$$

Then just backsubstitute from here.